# If $0 \leq a_{km} \leq a_{k(m+1)}$, $a_{km} \to a_m$ for each $m$ and $a_{km}$ is bounded, can we swtich double limits?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The question is summarized in the title.

Let $(a_{km})$ be a double sequence with non-negative values such that

1. $a_{km}$ is bounded for all $k, m \in \mathbb{N}$
2. $a_{km} \leq a_{k (m+1)}$ for all $k, m \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. $a_{km} \to A_m$ as $k \to \infty$ for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$ where $a_m$ is finite.
4. $a_{km} \to B_k$ as $m \to \infty$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ where $a_k$ is finite.

Then, the above three conditions imply that $A_m \to A$ as $m \to \infty$ for some $A \in [0,\infty)$ since $a_m$ is a bounded increasing sequence.

Now, my question is that, under such circumstances, can we conclude that:

$B_k$ has a limit as $k \to \infty$ and moreover,
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} a_{km} = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} a_{km}=A
\end{equation}
?

I have tried to combine the MCT and DCT, but cannot prove / disprove the above interchange of limits myself..

Could anyone pleae help me?

Comment: You cannot write $(a_m)$ and $(a_k)$ for two different sequences.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ohhh,,,I will change the notation to clarify,,

Comment: No (assume the obvious correction to (3) and (4)'s $a_k$ and $a_m$).  Consider the double sequence $a_{km}=1$ if $k<m$ and $0$ if $k\geq m$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

$B_k$ may not converge. Based on user10354138's example in the comment, consider

$$a_{k,m}=\left\{\begin{matrix}\ 0,\ \ \text{$k$ is even}\qquad\qquad\ \ \,\\\ 1,\ \ \text{$k$ is odd and $m\geq k$}\end{matrix}\right.$$

then all $4$ conditions are met and $B_k=(0,1,0,1,...)$ does not converge.

---

To ensure $\lim_mA_m=\lim_kB_k$, we need extra conditions. An example could be $a_{k,m}\leq a_{k+1,m}$, that is, $a_{k,m}$ is non-decreasing in both $k$ and $m$. Then we can conclude that

$$\lim_mA_m=\sup_{k,m}a_{k,m}=\lim_kB_k.$$

Another choice of conidtion is $a_{k,m}\to A_m$ uniformly in $m$ or $a_{k,m}\to B_k$ uniformly in $k$. This is a result by [Moore-Osgood theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Moore-Osgood_theorem_for_interchanging_limits).